# Difference between string primitive and string wrapper object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, primitive, string-literals

I'm very confused about what the [wrapper objects for primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). For example, a string primitive and a string created with the string wrapper object.

```
var a = "aaaa";
var b = new String("bbbb");
console.log(a.toUpperCase()); // AAAA
console.log(b.toUpperCase()); // BBBB
console.log(typeof a);        // string
console.log(typeof b);        // object
```

Both give access to `String.prototype` methods, and seem to act just like a string literal. But one is not a string, it's an object. What is the practical difference between `a` and `b`? Why would I create a string using `new String()`?

Comment: There's no real use case actually. The practical difference is that the string wrapper acts as an object (and for example can have own properties).

Answer (score 2):

A primitive string is not an object. An object string is an object.

Basically, that means:

- Object strings are compared by reference, not by the string they contain

  ```js
  "aaa" === "aaa";                         // true
  new String("aaa") === new String("aaa"); // false
  ```
- Object strings can store properties.

  ```js
  function addProperty(o) {
    o.foo = 'bar'; // Set a property
    return o.foo;  // Retrieve the value
  }
  addProperty("aaa");             // undefined
  addProperty(new String("aaa")); // "bar"
  ```