# String Declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, web

Following are some declaration of String in JAVASCRIPT

```
var str = "Hello World"
var str1 = new String("Hello World")
str2 = "Hello World"
```

What is the difference between declarations mentioned above. Memory wise or if any.

Comment: In JS there's absolutely no reason to use `new String()`, it's a weakly typed language and that should be taken advantage of

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951906/why-does-foo-new-stringfoo-evaluate-to-false-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ("foo" === new String("foo")) evaluate to false in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951906/why-does-foo-new-stringfoo-evaluate-to-false-in-javascript)

Comment: I read across various sites and books and came to these syntax's. I do not want to find the equality between them. i just want to know what is the difference.

Comment: @Adi7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984463/difference-between-string-primitive-and-string-wrapper-object-in-javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the top two are equivalent and the first is just syntactic sugar for the 2nd.

The 3rd assigns the `str2` variable to the global `window` scope. You can test this by going into the Chrome Dev tools and typing that line and inspecting it with the following line: `window.str2` will print the value you just assigned.